# Spark data frame is not utilizing the workers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark cluster with 3 worker nodes, when i try to load the csv file from hdfs it only utilizes the resources(cpu & memory) on the system where i load the csv via spark-shell (used master node)

Load dataframe

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
.option("header","true")
.load("hdfs://ipaddr:9000/user/smb_ram/2016_HDD.csv")
```

Do some operation on the dataframe

```
df.agg(sum("failure")).show
```

When i load csv system memory increases by 1.3 GB which is the hdfs file size & 100 % CPU usage. The workers were idling CPU near 0 % and no memory usage changes. Ideally i would expect all the heavy lifting to be done by worker which is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Set spark mode to cluster that should solve your problem. Looks like your job is running in Client mode.

Comment: How do i do that, could you please point to the resources.

Comment: You can search Spark Execution modes - I found following link helpful

https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/spark-modes-of-deployment/